# I thought Nick Fury went off the grid?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, nick-fury

After seeing him and Maria in the *Avengers: Infinity War* post credits scene, and seeing him again in the recent *Spider-Man: Far From Home* trailer, I was a bit confused. At the end of *Captain America: TheWinter Soldier*, he's not the Director of SHIELD anymore and he says he's going to finish off the rest of Hydra in Europe. But I took this to mean it would be one of his last missions. Does he still work undercover afterward, or did he retire?

Comment: "he's going to finish off the rest of Hydra in Europe" - _Far From Home_ takes place in Europe - why not?

Comment: I didn't connect those dots... makes more sense! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nick Fury took a leave of absence during the aftermath of *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*, but returned during the events of *Avengers: Age of Ultron* with a helicarrier to rescue the Avengers and numerous civilians from Sokovia. While he never officially returned to S.H.I.E.L.D. he remained in contact with the Avengers and continued to work with former S.H.I.E.L.D. agents like Maria Hill.

Comment: Ah ok. I jumped to conclusions by assuming he wasn't director. But since he was pronounced dead, doesn't the helicarrier raise any eyebrows for the media?

Comment: What newly reformed SHIELD?

Comment: Nick Fury never went back to become a part of SHIELD again.

Comment: You're correct, I'll edit my response to mention that.

Comment: @JackBNimble in Agents of Shield, the organisation is reformed (repeatedly, with varying levels of success and legal authority).

Comment: @OrangeDog Yes, but never run by Fury, and never mentioned again in the MCU, even though in AoS it is public and Mace has press conferences as SHIELD all the time, you never see even a hint of that see in in the films.

Comment: @OrangeDog the events of the MCU exist in AoS as it makes occasional reference to them, but the events of AoS do not exist in the MCU

Answer (score 2):

He does and mentions he is no longer a part of S.H.I.E.L.D. in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* when he pays a visit to Tony.

> **Nick Fury:** Look me in the eye and tell me you're going to shut him down.
>
> **Tony Stark:** You're not the director of me.
>
> **Nick Fury:** I'm not the director of anybody. I'm just an old man, who cares very much about you.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Age of Ultron*</sub>

Later on in the film it is made clear that the Helicarrier Fury brings to rescue everyone is no affiliated with S.H.I.E.L.D.

> **Nick Fury:** *[voice]* Glad you like the view, Romanoff. It's about to get better. *[just then the Helicarrier show up] [inside the Helicarrier]* Nice, right? I pulled her out of mothballs with a couple of old friends. She's dusty, but she'll do.
>
> **Steve Rogers:** Fury, you son of a bitch.
>
> **Nick Fury:** Oooh! You kiss your mother with that mouth?
>
> **Maria Hill:** Altitude is eighteen thousand and climbing.
>
> **Specialist Cameron Klein:** Lifeboats secure to deploy. Disengage in three, two...take 'em out. *[as they watch the lifeboats fly in towards the them]*
>
> **Pietro Maximoff:** This is SHIELD?
>
> **Steve Rogers:** This is what SHIELD's supposed to be.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Age of Ultron*</sub>

Comment: As revealed in Agents of Shield, that helicarrier is indeed provided by SHIELD.

Comment: @OrangeDog Hmm I've only watched the films in the MCU, got a reference for me to look at? Though the above could imply it is from S.H.I.E.L.D. I suppose with the _"with a couple of old friends."_ part though that could still just mean people he knew from S.H.I.E.L.D. and not necessarily S.H.I.E.L.D. itself.

Comment: https://ew.com/article/2015/05/05/agents-shield-age-ultron-crossover/

Comment: _"This is what SHIELD's supposed to be"_ Carrot, your misinterpreting that line. it isn't in any way a statement or indication that _"the Helicarrier Fury brings to rescue everyone is no affiliated with S.H.I.E.L.D."_, he's just saying that rescuing & protecting people is what SHIELD is supposed to be about, remember that Pietro's past experience of SHIELD have not been good ones & consider this chat between them in the correct & complete context of their previous conversations.

Comment: @Pelinore The way it is said is of course how you've interpreted it, I did too, but he doesn't actually say it is SHIELD which can further along with _"I pulled her out of mothballs with a couple of old friends. She's dusty, but she'll do."_ be interpreted to say it isn't SHIELD in my opinion.

Comment: I don't think the "mothball" line can be used to claim it's _definitely_ not a SHIELD operation either, from the film I find it ambiguous if this is actually "SHIELD" or just some old (previous SHIELD) members with some left over kit pulling together to help out : I do lean toward the later (so, _not_ SHIELD) as more likely but I don't think anything you've quoted can honestly be presented as "proof" of that opinion, that Fury isn't director of SHIELD is clearly said, but that SHIELD doesn't exist & these aren't part of it (with Fury just along for the ride) isn't.

Comment: @Pelinore I'm not saying it definitely isn't SHIELD just my interpretation of the it is that it isn't SHIELD. (Both scenes together not just the last one)

Comment: I agree with you, just that I'd say it was a balance of probability rather than a definite thing based on just that film.